# What might be causing momentary system freezes?

Tags: 11.10, system-monitor

I just built a new PC with pretty solid specs, at least, more robust than most I've built in the past.

It's got a six-core AMD processor, 600watt power supply, 8GB RAM, etc.

I loaded up a fresh copy of the latest Ubuntu 11.10 and prepared to be blown away.

However, while it runs fine, I'm seeing frequent lag, where the mouse stops dragging momentarily, tabs freeze in the browser under both Firefox and Chromium (with only 4-5 tabs too, not a huge number of tabs), etc. The system monitor looks great, everything is almost at the baseline-- it's not like I'm loading the CPU or using tons of RAM.

Is there any common thing I'm overlooking that would affect this?

Specs, for those who want to know:

```
Motherboard: Gigabyte GA970A-UD3
Processor: (FX-6100)
RAM: Corsair 2x4GB DDRIII
Graphics: NVidia N550GTX-Ti (1GB RAM)
```

Comment: More of a graphics issue than a processor or system malfunction. -BTW-  Overclocking? Should start with a full functioning system before modding the sets

Comment: @BlueXrider-- are you referring to the graphics card with the "overclocking" comment?

Comment: Actually no. I was speaking about the system as a whole. I was taught old-school, start with a working model then figure out how to break it.

Comment: I see-- ok, no, I've done nothing to overclock or make this any more exotic than a pretty decent machine to take over as my main dev/screwing around box. I'm not a real hardware guy though!

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know, I have seen this sort of problem with video drivers and less often even wireless drivers.

Which driver are you using for your nvidia card ?

See also : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Debugging

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had issues with the performance on my machine too and it turned out to be the twitter service each time it refreshed. Check disabling: `gwibber-service`
and you can check also this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181894/ubuntu-12-04-running-slow-how-to-improve-performance).